# Convert Single column list of dates into Multiple Date Range in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database

I had a business requirement which i need to convert the list dates into date range
Logic will be to create Date range upto continuous date if date is not in continuity then new range
will be created

Below is the sample table

```
  ID      Module  Employeeid   Date
    --------------------------------------------
    11      M1         9        2019-10-01 00:00:00.000 
    12      M1         9        2019-10-02 00:00:00.000 
    13      M1         9        2019-10-03 00:00:00.000 
    14      M2         9        2019-10-04 00:00:00.000 
    15      M2         9        2019-10-05 00:00:00.000
    16      M2         9        2019-10-08 00:00:00.000
    17      M2         9        2019-10-09 00:00:00.000
```

Requried Output

```
  Module  Employeeid   Start Date    End Date
    ---------------------------------------------------
    M1         9        2019-10-01  2019-10-03 
    M1         9        2019-10-04  2019-10-05
    M1         9        2019-10-08  2019-10-09
```

Below is the query which i have tried and it is working but we need to add from date and to date filter
so after adding filter OutPut is not proper

```
WITH mycte 
     AS (SELECT *, 
                Dateadd(day, -Row_number() 
                                OVER ( 
                                  partition BY [[module] 
                                  ORDER BY [Date]), [Date]) AS grp 
         FROM   [to_shiftschedule] 
         WHERE  employeeid = 535                 
               ) 
SELECT Min([Date]) AS[StartDate], 
       Max([Date]) AS[EndDate], 
       [employeeid], 
       [module] 
FROM   mycte 
where   CONVERT(VARCHAR, Date, 103) >= CONVERT(VARCHAR, '09/01/2020', 103) 
        AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, Date, 103) <= CONVERT(VARCHAR, '23/01/2020', 103)
GROUP  BY[employeeid], [module], grp 
ORDER  BY[startdate] DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is with date filter, which is this section, I assume

```
where   CONVERT(VARCHAR, Date, 103) >= CONVERT(VARCHAR, '09/01/2020', 103) 
    AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, Date, 103) <= CONVERT(VARCHAR, '23/01/2020', 103)
```

, the reason might be in comparing varchars instead of plain dates.

I suggest you use the following condition:

```
where Date >= '2020-01-09' and Date <= '2020-01-23'
```

By the way, I also advise you to edit your final SQL clause, because it is unclear which column you named as "Date".

Please let me know whether it helped or not.